# Mutual Information result in python for Feature selection unexpected result

Tags: feature-selection, mutual-information

I've started to study feature selection techniques and i have a situation that I don't understand.
I've created a synthetic dataset with 5 predictor variables and a label, the predictor variables are as follow:

X1 = random boolean (p=0.5)

X2 = random boolean (p=0.5)

X3 = random boolean (p=0.5)

X4 = XOR(X2, X3)

X5 = random boolean (p=0.5)

Y = XOR(X1, X2, X3)

So when I apply mutual information criteria to rank the relevance of the variables I'm getting that X5 is the most relevant, as far as I know it should be the lower in the rank because Y does not depend at all of it.

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.feature_selection import mutual_info_classif as MIC
from Py_FS.filter import Relief

SAMPLE_SIZE = 100

def xor_three(a, b, c):
    return (~a*~b*c)+(~a*b*~c)+(a*~b*~c)+(a*b*c)

def xor_two(a, b):
    return a != b

X1 = np.random.choice([False, True], size = SAMPLE_SIZE)
X2 = np.random.choice([False, True], size = SAMPLE_SIZE)
X3 = np.random.choice([False, True], size = SAMPLE_SIZE)
X4 = xor_two(X2, X3)
X5 = np.random.choice([False, True], size = SAMPLE_SIZE)
X = np.column_stack([X1,X2,X3,X4,X5])
Y  = xor_three(X1, X2, X3)

mi_score = MIC(X,Y, discrete_features=True)
print(mi_score)
```

As an example in one of the execution I've got in mi_score -> [0.00163452 0.00068499 0.00501039 0.01996895 0.02920959]

Not sure if I've missundertood the concept or I am doing something bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that none of your predictors are associated to the target (i.e. have a MI value that is not due to basically random noise).
Even though your target is calculated based on the three other predictors the resulting output is completely unrelated to any **single variable** that was used.
To give an easier example let us consider your `X4` as target variable which is calculated based only on `X2` and `X3`:

$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c}
X2 & X3 & X4\\
\hline
1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 
\end{array}
$$
If you calculate the mutual information between the columns of this table you get the following values:

$$
\begin{equation}
MI(X2;X4) = 0\\
MI(X3;X4) = 0
\end{equation}
$$

There is no association between input and output.
The same would happen with your `xor_three` function.
That `X5` obtains the largest MI value in your example is just due to randomness. You could repeat it and get another variable as top predictor.